# comma operator with declarations in a for-loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, declaration, let, comma-operator

In the following JavaScript code block I do NOT want to declare a new function `f` in the `for`-scope but just to assign `() => i` to the previously declared `let f`, thus creating a closure to the `for`-scoped declared and defined variable `i`.

Unfortunately the code results in a `Type Error: f is not a function` because `f = () => i` is being interpreted as `let f = () => i`:

```
{
    let f;
    for (let i = 'a', f = () => i; i == 'a'; ) {
        i = 'b';
    }
    f();
}
```

In the `for`-loop, how can I separate `f = () => i` from the precedent `let i = 'a'`?

Putting it in parentheses results in a `Syntax Error`:

```
{
    let f;
    for ((let i = 'a'), f = () => i; i == 'a'; ) {
        i = 'b';
    }
    f();
}
```

I don't want to change the scopes. I'm just looking for a syntactic mean to express the exactly scope constellation as given in my question.

Comment: Any reason why you want to avoid assigning f in the body of the loop?

Comment: @kuzyn Yes, the closure (between `f` and `i`) would be different since the variable `i` in the `for`-block has another scope as the variable `i` in the `for (...; ...; ...)`. Though this is not obvious.

Comment: I think we need to see an actual example of what your trying to achieve here. You obviously simplified version is a bit contrived @Min-SooPipefeet

Comment: @Liam Yes, it is absolutely contrived as it's just a study about the use of the comma operator in the `for`-loop (and not about arrow-functions). That's why `comma` shouldn't be removed from the keywords, and `arrow-functions` shouldn't be added.

Comment: Notice that `,` is not the comma operator here, it's the delimiter between multiple variable declarations (like in a normal multiline declaration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution:

```
{
    let f;
    for (let i = (f = () => i, 'a'); i == 'a'; ) {
        i = 'b';
    }
    f();
}
```

Or with an additional dummy-helper:

```
{
    let f;
    for (let i = 'a', dummy = (f = () => i, 'ignore'); i == 'a'; ) {
        i = 'b';
    }
    f();
}
```

Comment: Yes, the parenthesis make this expression have an actual comma operator. Btw, you should add a disclaimer in your answer that this is absolutely horrible syntax and should never be used in real code :-)

Comment: Btw, an alternative to the comma operator (better than the dummy variable) is using an IIFE: `let i = (()=>{ f = …; return 'a'; })();`

Comment: @Bergi Yes, using an IIFE is a better option than the dummy variable. But still much more horrible than `let i = (f = ...; 'a')` :-)

Comment: The whole thing of doing effects from within the short-lived loop head initialisation scope is so horrible that all of these alternatives don't give much :-)

Comment: @Bergi Absolutely! I needed them only to find out and to assert that there is actually an own "loop head initialisation scope"! OMG! :-) - Is that a bug or a feature of JS? And if it's a feature: where is it specified?